# Special tensor contraction in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I need to perform a special type of tensor contraction. I want something of this kind:

> A_{bg} = Sum_{a,a',a''} ( B_{a} C_{a'b} D_{a''g} )

where all the indices can have values 0,1 and the sum over a, a' and a'' is carried for all cases where a+a'+a'' = 1 or a+a'+a'' = 2. So it is like the reverse of the Einstein summation convention: I want to sum only when one of the three indices is different to the others.

Moreover, I want some flexibility with the number of indices that are not being summed: in the example the resulting tensor has 2 indices, and the sum is over products of elements of 3 tensors, one with one index, the other two with two indices. These numbers of indices are going to vary, so in general I would like to be able to write something like this:

> A_{...} = Sum_{a,a',a''} ( B_{a...} C_{a...} D_{a''...} )

I want to point that the number of indices is not fixed, but it is controlled: I can know and specify how many indices every tensor has in each step.

I tried `np.einsum()`, but then apparently I am forced to sum over repeated indices in the standard Einstein convention, and I don't know how to implement the condition I exposed here.

And I cannot write everything with various **for** because, as I said, the number of indices of the tensors involved is not fixed.

Anyone has an idea?

---

#### From comments:

I would write what I put here in programming language like this:

```
tensa = np.zeros((2,2))
for be in range(2):
    for ga in range(2):
        for al in range(2):
            for alp in range(2):
                for alpp in range(res(al,alp),prod(al,alp)):
                    tensa[be,ga] += tensb[al] * tensc[alp,be] * tensd[alpp,ga]
```

where `res` and `prod` are two functions that ensure that `al+alp+alpp = 1 or 2`. The problem with this is that I need to specify all the indices involved, and I cannot do that in the general calculation for all the lattice.

Comment: Can you give more information. Over what space are you working. Are you summing over a permutation group of some sort? Are you working on a tangent space of a manifold?

Comment: Can you rewrite this using programming notation instead of math notation?

Comment: @kolonel I'm working on a triangular lattice, and I'm making a tensor contraction on each triangle. The lattice is made up of antiferromagnetic spins, which means that in each triangle there has to be two "0" and one "1", or one "0" and two "1", so this is the subspace relevant to me. I don't know if mathematically there is a name for that subspace :)

Comment: @Slater Tyranus I would write what I put here in programming language like this:

tensa=np.zeros((2,2))

for be in range(2):
  for ga in range(2):
    for al in range(2):
     for alp in range(2):
        for alpp in range(res(al,alp),prod(al,alp)):
             tensa[be,ga]=tensa[be,ga]+\
             tensb[al]*tensc[alp,be]*\
             tensd[alpp,ga]

where _res_ and _prod_ are two functions that ensure that al+alp+alpp = 1 or 2. The problem with this is that I need to specify all the indices involved, and I cannot do that in the general calculation for all the lattice.

Comment: A k-Tensor is a multilinear function that maps its input which will be k-vectors to the real numbers, so in the question when you said "and the sum is over products of elements of 3 tensors" , are you referring to a function that takes 3 vectors?

Comment: The index notation for a cross product ε{ijk} might give you some ideas.  With an appropriately defined 3d `LC` array, `np.cross(x,y)==np.einsum('i,ijk,k->j',x,LC,y)`.  With a couple of Levi-Civita like arrays you could probably produce your desired product using `einsum`.

Comment: @hpaulj If I did the math properly, the OP's first example would have to run through `8*b*g` items, and for each perform 2 multiplications and an addition. If a 'Levi-Civita like' array is added, then there would be 3 multiplications and an addition per item. The method in my answer requires two passes of `np.einsum`, so in total there are `32*b*g` multiplications, `16*b*g` additions, and an extra `b*g` subtractions to compute the end result. With the method you propose, there should only be `24*b*g` multiplications and `8*b*g` additions, so it should be noticeably faster [continues]

Comment: @hpaulj [continued] But I went ahead and implemented it, and to my surprise it actually runs twice as slow as the two passes through the array. I'm guessing it's some iterator inefficiency causing this unexpected poor performance. What do you think? I will add my code to the end of my answer, for reference.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  `einsum` treats cases with 2 (maybe 3) arguments and dimensions as special cases, but this could require the general purpose calculator (using `nditer` in C).  Looks like the `op_axes` for setting up the `nditer` will have 5 terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, lets write your example out in Python loops, to have a baseline for comparisons. If I understood you correctly, this is what you want to do:

```
b, g = 4, 5
B = np.random.rand(2)
C = np.random.rand(2, b)
D = np.random.rand(2, g)

out = np.zeros((b, g))
for j in (0, 1):
    for k in (0, 1):
        for l in (0, 1):
            if j + k + l in (1, 2):
                out += B[j] * C[k, :, None] * D[l, None, :]
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
>>> out
array([[ 1.27679643,  2.26125361,  1.32775173,  1.5517918 ,  0.47083151],
       [ 0.84302586,  1.57516142,  1.1335904 ,  1.14702252,  0.34226837],
       [ 0.70592576,  1.34187278,  1.02080112,  0.99458563,  0.29535054],
       [ 1.66907981,  3.07143067,  2.09677013,  2.20062463,  0.65961165]])
```

You can't get at this directly with `np.einsum`, but you can run it twice and get your result as the difference of these two:

```
>>> np.einsum('i,jk,lm->km', B, C, D) - np.einsum('i,ik,im->km', B, C, D)
array([[ 1.27679643,  2.26125361,  1.32775173,  1.5517918 ,  0.47083151],
       [ 0.84302586,  1.57516142,  1.1335904 ,  1.14702252,  0.34226837],
       [ 0.70592576,  1.34187278,  1.02080112,  0.99458563,  0.29535054],
       [ 1.66907981,  3.07143067,  2.09677013,  2.20062463,  0.65961165]])
```

The first call to `np.einsum` is adding everything up, regardless of what the indices add up to. The second only adds up those where all three indices are the same. So obviously your result is the difference of the two.

Ideally, you could now go on to write something like:

```
>>>(np.einsum('i...,j...,k...->...', B, C, D) -
... np.einsum('i...,i...,i...->...', B, C, D))
```

and get your result regardless of the dimensions of your C and D arrays. If you try the first, you will get the following error message:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes
[original->remapped]: (2)->(2,newaxis,newaxis) (2,4)->(4,newaxis,2,newaxis)
                      (2,5)->(5,newaxis,newaxis,2)
```

The problem is that, since you are not specifying what you want to do with the `b` and `g` dimensions of your tensors, it tries to broadcast them together, and since they are different, it fails. You can get it to work by adding extra dimensions of size 1:

```
>>> (np.einsum('i...,j...,k...->...', B, C, D[:, None]) -
...  np.einsum('i...,i...,i...->...', B, C, D[:, None]))
array([[ 1.27679643,  2.26125361,  1.32775173,  1.5517918 ,  0.47083151],
       [ 0.84302586,  1.57516142,  1.1335904 ,  1.14702252,  0.34226837],
       [ 0.70592576,  1.34187278,  1.02080112,  0.99458563,  0.29535054],
       [ 1.66907981,  3.07143067,  2.09677013,  2.20062463,  0.65961165]])
```

If you wanted all the axes of B to be placed before all the axes of C, and these before all the axes of D, the following seems to work, at least as far as creating an output of the right shape, although you may want to double check that the result is really what you want:

```
>>> B = np.random.rand(2, 3)
>>> C = np.random.rand(2, 4, 5)
>>> D = np.random.rand(2, 6)
>>> C_idx = (slice(None),) + (None,) * (B.ndim - 1)
>>> D_idx = C_idx + (None,) * (C.ndim - 1)
>>> (np.einsum('i...,j...,k...->...', B, C[C_idx], D[D_idx]) -
...  np.einsum('i...,i...,i...->...', B, C[C_idx], D[D_idx])).shape
(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)
```

---

**EDIT** From the comments, if instead of just the first axis of each tensor having to be reduced over, it is the first two, then the above could be written as:

```
>>> B = np.random.rand(2, 2, 3)
>>> C = np.random.rand(2, 2, 4, 5)
>>> D = np.random.rand(2, 2, 6)
>>> C_idx = (slice(None),) * 2 + (None,) * (B.ndim - 2)
>>> D_idx = C_idx + (None,) * (C.ndim - 2)
>>> (np.einsum('ij...,kl...,mn...->...', B, C[C_idx], D[D_idx]) -
...  np.einsum('ij...,ij...,ij...->...', B, C[C_idx], D[D_idx])).shape
(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)
```

More generally, if reducing over `d` indices, `C_idx` and `D_idx` would look like:

```
>>> C_idx = (slice(None),) * d + (None,) * (B.ndim - d)
>>> D_idx = C_idx + (None,) * (C.ndim - d)
```

and the calls to `np.einsum` would need to have `d` letters in the indexing, unique in the first call, repeating in the second.

---

**EDIT 2** So what exactly goes on with `C_idx` and `D_idx`? Take the last example, with `B`, `C` and `D` with shapes `(2, 2, 3)`, `(2, 2, 4, 5)` and `(2, 2, 6)`. `C_idx` is made up of two empty slices, plus as many `None`s as the number of dimensions of `B` minus 2, so when we take `C[C_idx]` the result has shape `(2, 2, 1, 4, 5)`. Similarly `D_idx` is `C_idx` plus as many `None`s as the number of dimensions of `C` minus 2, so the result of `D[D_idx]` has shape `(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6)`. These three arrays don't braodcast together, but `np.einsum` adds additional dimensions of size 1, i.e. the "remapped" shapes of the error above, so the resulting arrays turn out to have extra trailing ones, and the shapes amtch as follows:

```
(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1)
(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6)
```

The first two axes are reduced, so the disappear from the output, and in the other cases, broadcasting applies, where a dimension of size 1 is replicated to match a larger one, so the output is `(3, 4, 5, 6)` as we wanted.

---

@hpaulj proposes a method using "Levi-Civita like" tensors, that should in theory be faster, see my comments to the original question. Here's some code for comparison:

```
b, g = 5000, 2000
B = np.random.rand(2)
C = np.random.rand(2, b)
D = np.random.rand(2, g)

def calc1(b, c, d):
    return (np.einsum('i,jm,kn->mn', b, c, d) -
            np.einsum('i,im,in->mn', b, c, d))

def calc2(b, c, d):
    return np.einsum('ijk,i,jm,kn->mn', calc2.e, b, c, d)
calc2.e = np.ones((2,2,2))
calc2.e[0, 0, 0] = 0
calc2.e[1, 1, 1] = 0
```

But when running it:

```
%timeit calc1(B, C, D)
1 loops, best of 3: 361 ms per loop

%timeit calc2(B, C, D)
1 loops, best of 3: 643 ms per loop

np.allclose(calc1(B, C, D), calc2(B, C, D))
Out[48]: True
```

A surprising result, which I can't explain...

Comment: Your answer is great! I have almost achieved my desired result, but still I'm getting more axes than there should be (I'm contracting a 2,2 with a 2,2,2,2 and another 2,2,2,2 and should get a 2,2,2,2, but am getting a 2,2,2,2,2,2 , with the two extra axes full of zeros). Probably the problem is that I am not understanding these lines: C_idx = (slice(None),) + (None,) * (B.ndim - 1)
>>> D_idx = C_idx + (None,) * (C.ndim - 1). Could you explain them better? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand what's happening partially: If I copy exactly your code and apply it to my example, I get a tensor with dimension 7, which is the expected thing since I am contracting 3 out of 10 total dimensions. But I wanted to contract two indices for each tensor, a, a' and a'' and b, b' and b'', each group of 3 fulfilling the condition of summation 1 or 2. So instead of i...,j...,k... i wrote ij...,kl...,mn... but it's not working as expected because i'm getting a result of dimension 6 where I would want a result of dimension 4.

Comment: Can you spell out the indices you want to sum over in your example? If your three tensors have axes `ab`, `cdef` and  `ghij`, then the way I've written it, only the first axis of each is summed over, so the output will have shape `bdefhij`. Try spelling out exactly what you are after, which I am guessing is something like `np.einsum('ij,klmn,opqr->mnqr', B, C, D) - np.einsum('ij,ijmn,ijqr->mnqr', B, C, D)`.

Comment: Yes, what I want is exactly what you are guessing. When I wrote it like you just did, it worked, but of course I would like to write it as something like np.einsum(ij...,kl...,mn...->,B,C,D) - np.einsum('ij...,ij...,ij...->---', B, C, D) in order to cope with the variable number of indices. But this is not working, even with the C_idx and D_idx added.

Comment: You will need a different call signature depending on how many indices you want to reduce over, let me edit my answer to include the 2 index case, hopefully this will make it clear how to expand it to 3 or more if you ever need it.

Comment: There you go, see if it makes sense.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Could you just write briefly what are the functions C_idx and D_idx doing? I guess it's something about creating new axes, but I don't completely get it.

Comment: See my second edit. It's kind of hard to grasp of broadcasting until you get the hang of it, just keep banging your head against it until it starts making sense!