# cross products with einsums

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cross-product, numpy-einsum

I'm trying to compute the cross-products of many 3x1 vector pairs as fast as possible. This

```
n = 10000
a = np.random.rand(n, 3)
b = np.random.rand(n, 3)
numpy.cross(a, b)
```

gives the correct answer, but motivated by [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910319/353337), I thought that `einsum` would get me somewhere. I found that both

```
eijk = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))
eijk[0, 1, 2] = eijk[1, 2, 0] = eijk[2, 0, 1] = 1
eijk[0, 2, 1] = eijk[2, 1, 0] = eijk[1, 0, 2] = -1

np.einsum('ijk,aj,ak->ai', eijk, a, b)
np.einsum('iak,ak->ai', np.einsum('ijk,aj->iak', eijk, a), b)
```

compute the cross product, but their performance is disappointing: Both methods perform much worse than `np.cross`:

```
%timeit np.cross(a, b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 628 µs per loop
```

```
%timeit np.einsum('ijk,aj,ak->ai', eijk, a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.02 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit np.einsum('iak,ak->ai', np.einsum('ijk,aj->iak', eijk, a), b)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

Any ideas of how to improve the `einsum`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count of multiply operation of `einsum()` is more then `cross()`, and in the newest NumPy version, `cross()` doesn't create many temporary arrays. So `einsum()` can't be faster than `cross()`.

Here is the old code of cross:

```
x = a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1]
y = a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2]
z = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
```

Here is the new code of cross:

```
multiply(a1, b2, out=cp0)
tmp = array(a2 * b1)
cp0 -= tmp
multiply(a2, b0, out=cp1)
multiply(a0, b2, out=tmp)
cp1 -= tmp
multiply(a0, b1, out=cp2)
multiply(a1, b0, out=tmp)
cp2 -= tmp
```

To speedup it, you need cython or numba.

Comment: And since these don't involve loops the `cython` improvement might not be significant.  When expressed like this `cross` is more of an algebraic operation than an array one.

Answer (score 5):

You can bring in matrix-multiplication using [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) to lose one of the dimensions at the first level and then use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to lose the other dimension, like so -

```
np.einsum('aik,ak->ai',np.tensordot(a,eijk,axes=([1],[1])),b)
```

Alternatively, we can perform broadcasted elementwise multiplications between `a` and `b` using `np.einsum` and then lose the two dimensions in one go with `np.tensordot`, like so -

```
np.tensordot(np.einsum('aj,ak->ajk', a, b),eijk,axes=([1,2],[1,2]))
```

We could have performed the elementwise multiplications by introducing new axes too with something like `a[...,None]*b[:,None]`, but it seems to slow it down.

---

Though, these show good improvement over the proposed `np.einsum` only based approaches, but fail to beat `np.cross`.

Runtime test -

```
In [26]: # Setup input arrays
    ...: n = 10000
    ...: a = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    ...: 

In [27]: # Time already posted approaches
    ...: %timeit np.cross(a, b)
    ...: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,aj,ak->ai', eijk, a, b)
    ...: %timeit np.einsum('iak,ak->ai', np.einsum('ijk,aj->iak', eijk, a), b)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 298 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.29 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.einsum('aik,ak->ai',np.tensordot(a,eijk,axes=([1],[1])),b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 838 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit np.tensordot(np.einsum('aj,ak->ajk',a,b),eijk,axes=([1,2],[1,2]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 882 µs per loop
```