# Fast scalar triple product in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large number of vector triples, and I would like to compute the [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product) for them. I can do

```
import numpy

n = 871
a = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)
b = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)
c = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)

# <a, b x c>
omega = numpy.einsum('ij, ij->i', a, numpy.cross(b, c))
```

but `numpy.cross` is fairly slow. The symmetry of the problem (its Levi-Civita expression is `eps_{ijk} a_i b_j c_k`) suggests that there might be a better (faster) way to compute it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any hints?

Comment: Past questions have shown that for what it does, the current `cross` is efficient, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39662540/901925

Comment: Cross products alone are fine, this one is with a dot product that gives it a particular symmetry. It strikes me as odd that there should be no further optimization for it.

Comment: if A, B and C are specific 3-vectors, the Einstein notation you are looking for is `\epsilon_{ijk} A^i B^j C^k`, when epsilon is the Levi-Civita symbol. It don't think it's something that have been implemented in `numpy.einsum`.
as @B. M. said, It is exactly equivalent to the det of `np.dstack(A, B, C)`.

Comment: A previous use of Levi-Civita in `einsum` http://stackoverflow.com/a/20910319/901925.  The new `optimize` might improve that performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a comparison of the methods mentioned in the answers.
The results:

[image]

@Divakar's beats the einsum-cross one by a bit.

For the sake of completeness, let me note that there is another method solely relying on dot-products and a sqrt, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148866/36678). That method is slightly slower than both einsum-cross and slice-sum.

---

The plot was created with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot),

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def einsum_cross(a, b, c):
    return np.einsum("ij, ij->i", a, np.cross(b, c))


def det(a, b, c):
    return np.linalg.det(np.dstack([a, b, c]))


def slice_sum(a, b, c):
    c0 = b[:, 1] * c[:, 2] - b[:, 2] * c[:, 1]
    c1 = b[:, 2] * c[:, 0] - b[:, 0] * c[:, 2]
    c2 = b[:, 0] * c[:, 1] - b[:, 1] * c[:, 0]
    return a[:, 0] * c0 + a[:, 1] * c1 + a[:, 2] * c2


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: (
        np.random.rand(n, 3),
        np.random.rand(n, 3),
        np.random.rand(n, 3),
    ),
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1, 20)],
    kernels=[einsum_cross, det, slice_sum],
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just the determinant.

```
omega=det(dstack([a,b,c]))
```

But it is slower....

An other equivalent solution is `omega=dot(a,cross(b,c)).sum(1)` .

But I think you have to compute about 9 (for cross) + 3 (for dot) + 2 (for sum) = 14 operations for each det, so it seems to be near optimal. At best you will win a two factor in numpy.

**EDIT:**

If speed is critical, you must go at low level.  `numba`  is a easy way to do that  for  a 15X factor here :

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def multidet(a,b,c):
    n=a.shape[0]
    d=np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        u,v,w=a[i],b[i],c[i]
        d[i]=\
        u[0]*(v[1]*w[2]-v[2]*w[1])+\
        u[1]*(v[2]*w[0]-v[0]*w[2])+\
        u[2]*(v[0]*w[1]-v[1]*w[0])  # 14 operations / det
    return d
```

some tests:

```
In [155]: %timeit multidet(a,b,c)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.79 µs per loop

In [156]: %timeit numpy.einsum('ij, ij->i', a, numpy.cross(b, c))
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop


In [159]: allclose(multidet(a,b,c),omega)
Out[159]: True
```

Comment: From `numpy.linalg.det`: `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`. Note that I need to compute many scalar triple products at once.

Comment: I correct the det version, but it is not optimized. I add an other solution, hope it can help.

Comment: Numba! When  everything else fails! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach making use of `slicing` and summing -

```
def slicing_summing(a,b,c):
    c0 = b[:,1]*c[:,2] - b[:,2]*c[:,1]
    c1 = b[:,2]*c[:,0] - b[:,0]*c[:,2]
    c2 = b[:,0]*c[:,1] - b[:,1]*c[:,0]
    return a[:,0]*c0 + a[:,1]*c1 + a[:,2]*c2
```

We can replace the first three steps that compute `c0, c1, c2` and its stacked version with a one-liner, like so -

```
b[:,[1,2,0]]*c[:,[2,0,1]] - b[:,[2,0,1]]*c[:,[1,2,0]]
```

This would create another `(n,3)` array, which has to used with `a` for sum-reduction resulting in a `(n,)` shaped array. With the proposed `slicing_summing` method, we are directly getting to that `(n,)` shaped array with summing of those three slices and thus avoiding that intermediate `(n,3)` array.

Sample run -

```
In [86]: # Setup inputs    
    ...: n = 871
    ...: a = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    ...: c = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    ...: 

In [87]: # Original approach
    ...: omega = np.einsum('ij, ij->i', a, np.cross(b, c))

In [88]: np.allclose(omega, slicing_summing(a,b,c))
Out[88]: True
```

Runtime test -

```
In [90]: %timeit np.einsum('ij, ij->i', a, np.cross(b, c))
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.6 µs per loop

In [91]: %timeit slicing_summing(a,b,c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 63 µs per loop
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to implement this using the "one-liner" version? I'm not sure what you mean by "sum-reduction" in this case. Is there some clever trick to multiply the columns of two arrays pairwise, and sum the results?