# Numpy cross product matrix function

Tags: numpy

Is there a Numpy built-in function that returns a [cross product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication)?

That is:

```
>>> cross_product_matrix_function([1, 2, 3])
array([[ 0, -3,  2],
       [ 3,  0, -1],
       [-2,  1,  0]])
```

Comment: I think you could just [contract the input with the Levi-Civita tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910319/1346276); but then, that itself has to be built manually.

Comment: `np.cross(a, np.identity(a.shape[0]) * -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3x3 matricies:

```
import numpy as np

I = np.eye(3)

def cross_product_matrix_function(m):
    return np.cross(I, m)

print(cross_product_matrix_function([1, 2, 3]))
```